# Assign keywords to Bookmarks in Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

In Firefox, I can assign a keyword to a bookmark. For example if I assign "s" to "something.com" then I can go to the URL bar, enter "s" hit enter and the browser navigates to "something.com".

Is it possible to achieve the same in Chromium?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no official way of doing that, but there is one **hack** you can use:

1. Right-click the Omnibox (address bar) and click "**Edit search engines...**"
2. Under '**Other search engines**' click **ADD** button
3. Enter **keyword** and **URL** you want your keyword to go to
   (search engine input is just for naming type whatever you want).

[source](http://lifehacker.com/5476033/how-to-set-keyword-bookmarks-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

For accessing bookmarks using keywords there is a Chrome extension called [Bookmark Keyword](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-keyword/jgmmhndnlacimnjmgplphnokhnlbhnmd) by Alex Nazimok.

In the bookmark's title you have to prepend the keyword in square brackets, e.g. `[so] stackoverflow`. Then you can access this bookmark by entering `kw so` into the address bar (`kw` stands for "keyword").